# how to do a foreach loop in php?

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework, foreach

I have a function that has a query and a foreach loop:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM explore WHERE id = $id";
$object = $this->db->select($sql);

foreach($object as $val){
    $results = array('id'=>$val->id, 'from_id'=>$val->from_id);
    $this->result[] = $this->notify($results);  
    }

return $results;
```

The issue here is that if I `return $object` I get 2 records:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [from_id] => 6
        [id] => 3
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [from_id] => 6
        [id] => 1
    )

)
```

and `return $results` has 1 record:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [from_id] => 6
)
```

Also if I `return $this->result;`, `$this->result[] = $this->notify($results);` does run twice but uses the same record twice returned by `$results` instead of using the 2 records from `$object`

Hope you guys can understand my issue.

ps: I am using the zend framework

Any ideas?

**Edit**: `notify` is a function in another class

Comment: Where are the variables `$getResults` and `$this->result` coming from, and what is `$this->notify`?  What do you want the resulting array to look like?

Comment: Sorry, where exactly did you assign a value to `$getResults`?

Comment: my bad, i was talking about `$results`, please rank this question up, it is valid question, if we look over some of my typing mistakes

Comment: What is your concrete question? What you describe as issue(s), is just telling that your code works as it should. Obviously it does not what you expect, so what do you expect it to do? What do you want to do?

Comment: the issue with return `$this->result` is that i get 2 results, but they use the first result from `$results` instead of using both results from the array. `$results` has 2 results in the array, 0 and 1. return `$this->result` will use 0 twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$getResults` isn't being set anywhere in your code, visibly.  It looks like you ought to be returning `$this->result` instead, as that's where the results are being stored. That's my best guess given the amount of code you've given us. If you can provide more code, I can further update my answer if it doesn't work for you.

Given your comment, update your code to this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM explore WHERE id = $id";
$object = $this->db->select($sql);

foreach($object as $val){
    $results = array('id'=>$val->id, 'from_id'=>$val->from_id);
    $this->result[] = $this->notify($results);  
    }

return $this->result;
```

If you're only returning `$results`, it'll be filled with the last item, not every item.

Comment: the issue with `return $this->result;` is that i get 2 results, but they use the first result from `$results`instead of using both results from the array.

`$results` has 2 results in the array, 0 and 1. `return $this->result;` will use 0 twice

Comment: @Patrioticcow: Then that sounds like an issue in your code elsewhere. What does `$this->notify` do?

Comment: `$this->notify` returns some other content

Answer (score 2):

The reason you have a problem is that you redefine the `$results` array on each iteration of the `foreach` loop, instead of adding an element to it.

This is where the problem is:

```
//...
foreach($object as $val){
    $results = array('id'=>$val->id, 'from_id'=>$val->from_id);
//...        ^ you are reassigning the whole value of $results
```

Do this instead:

```
//...
$results = array();
foreach($object as $val){
    $results[] = array('id'=>$val->id, 'from_id'=>$val->from_id);
//...       ^^ note the array push instead of complete reassign
```

**EDIT** as @Cyclone has rightly pointed out, the above answer is in fact wrong. You need to be doing one of two things:

- returning `$this->result` instead of `$results`
- populating the `$results` variable with the processed data, instead of `$this->result`.

Essentially, you either need to change:

```
return $results;
```

to:

```
return $this->result;
```

Or, change the loop to this:

```
$results = array();
foreach($object as $val){
    $results[] = $this->notify(array('id'=>$val->id, 'from_id'=>$val->from_id));  
}
```

Which one you want to do depends on whether you actually need `$this->result` - i.e. whether you need to keep the results in the object after this code has executed.

Comment: -1, the results array should be pushed through the `$this->notify` function with each pass, as you can see in OP's code. Fix that and I'll change my vote, fairly.

Comment: @Cyclone You are absolutely right and I have edited my answer and +1ed yours. Didn't pay complete attention to the whole code, always a mistake...